# Finding indexes in python

Tags: python, indexing, tkinter

I'm trying to find indexes in python when using tkinter and I keep getting this problem. I know that the line index starts from 1 and the column index starts from 0 but when I try to find the index after 1.9 I can't because it makes sense to be 2.0 after 1.9 but it's not. For example

```
self.t1 = Text(self, width = 35, height = 5, wrap = WORD)
self.t1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
self.t1.insert(1.0, 'Q')
self.t1.insert(1.1, 'W')
self.t1.insert(1.2, 'E')
self.t1.insert(1.3, 'R')
self.t1.insert(1.4, 'T')
self.t1.insert(1.5, 'Y')
self.t1.insert(1.6, 'U')
self.t1.insert(1.7, 'I')
self.t1.insert(1.8, 'O')
self.t1.insert(1.9, 'P')
self.t1.insert(1.?, 'A') #What index comes after 1.9 but not 2.0
                         #because that would mean it'd be on a new line. 
self.t1.get(1.?, 1.?)    #I'm not sure what index I'm looking for to find 'A'
```

Also when I try to use 3 decimal point numbers e.g. `1.01`. It works fine but when I get to `1.08` as an index I get this error:

```
self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index, chars) + args)
_tkinter.TclError: bad text index "1.08"
```

I get the same error for `1.09` too but not `1.10`. Why is that?

They're probably really easy to figure out but I serious have no idea how to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Tkinter Text widget index looks like a decimal number, but is actually a string, so the value must be placed in quotes.  It consists of two parts separated by a dot: "line.column" so the next column after "1.9" is "1.10".  "2.0" is the leftmost column of the second line.

Comment: That is correct but python interprets '1.10' as '1.1' because behind '1.1' is an infinite amount of zeros. So if you put '1.10000000' it would still be the same as '1.1' pretty much. I put '1.11' as the next one and it works but there is a random letter there from the code that I am using. After '1.9' isn't '1.10' or '1.11' so I'm completely confused on that one.

Comment: @user2387537: you are confusing floating point numbers with strings. If you actually pass `1.10` to the text widget it will get interpreted as the string `"1.1"`, but what else would you expect? You should never be using floating point numbers as text widget indexes for precisely this reason. They only _look_ like floating point numbers. In the tkinter text widget, `"1.10"` will always following `"1.9"`.